# Flutter - Reduce size of row to necessary space

Tags: flutter

I would like to create a container that contains a row of
a text widget, a sizedBox and an IconButton (to delete this container).

The container should size itself to the children, that means the row

> Containers with no children try to be as big as possible unless the incoming constraints are unbounded, in which case they try to be as small as possible. Containers with children size themselves to their children. The width, height, and constraints arguments to the constructor override this. (From [the flutter webpage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html).)

The row expands as much as possible, but I would like it to be as small as possible. The container (in particular its borders) should be as small as possible

```
  Widget chipForm(String chipText){
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
            width: 3.0
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(5.0)
        ),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Text(chipText),
          SizedBox(width : 10),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
            onPressed: (){},
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 9):

The `Row` widget has a property `mainAxisSize` which is

> How much space should be occupied in the main axis.

Set this to `MainAxisSize.min` which

> Minimize[s] the amount of free space along the main axis, subject to the incoming layout constraints.

to shrink the `Row` as much as possible.

Example:

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Text(chipText),
    SizedBox(width : 10),
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
      onPressed: (){},
    )
  ],
),
```

You should check the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) before asking here.